# Problems with Case statements in MacOS ZSH

Tags: macos, shell, sh, zsh

I'm trying to run an exercise code about "case" statement in the ZSH shell of MacOS Monterey. My code is not simple do describe but, in a nutshell, the code simply receives a positive integer number and should pass one of these statements + the final statement.
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/zsh
    Bin=$(bc <<< "obase=2; $1")
Zeros=0000
Len=${#Bin}
Bin=${Zeros:$len}$Bin
case $Bin in 
    1[01][01][01]) echo Error type 8 ;;&
    [01]1[01][01]) echo Error type 4 ;;&
    [01][01]1[01]) echo Error type 2 ;;&
    [01][01][01]1) echo Error type 1 ;;&
             0000) echo No Error ;;&
                *) echo Final Binary: $Bin
esac
```

But the shell gives this error message:

```
case.sh:17: parse error near `&'
```

I tried to change `;;&` to `;|` but it gives me another error message:

```
/case.sh:18: parse error near `)'
```

After one hour of thinking, I couldn't reach a solution.

The input of code:

```
$ case.sh 5
```

The code should return:

```
Error type 4
Error type 1
Final Binary:0101
```

Can somebody gives me a hand on this? Please?

Comment: The terminator is either `;;` or `;&`; `;;&` is a syntax error, as reported.

Comment: It's also `;|`, not `|;`.

Comment: You may want to read the documentation for `case` statements in `man zshmisc` more carefully.

Comment: You would get the same error if you just write a lone `&` on the command line. `A&B` means to run command A in the background, and immediately start command B. You don't have any command to the left of your `&` and this causes the syntax error.

Comment: @user1934428 That's not really relevant; `;&` is a valid case terminator; `;;&` is not. Different parsing rules apply inside compound statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of my code:

```
#!/bin/zsh
Bin=$(bc <<< "obase=2; $1")
Zeros=000
Len=${#Bin}
Bin=${Zeros:$len}$Bin

case $Bin in 
    [0-9]*1[01][01][01]) echo Error type 8 ;|
    [0-9]*[01]1[01][01]) echo Error type 4 ;|
    [0-9]*[01][01]1[01]) echo Error type 2 ;|
    [0-9]*[01][01][01]1) echo Error type 1 ;|
             0000) echo No Error ;|
                *) echo Final binary: $Bin ;;
esac
```